# JQuery to reorder complex divs by custom property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried 20 different variations on re-ordering a list of items with JQuery, and every last one of them has failed to be what I needed. So, here's the simple:

I have a div with a series of divs insiside (with nested divs in them!). Divs are added to this series via other functionality, and the order isn't taken into account.

```
<div class="span12" style="padding: 10px;" id="DLRemRows" name="DLRemRows">
    <strong>Member of Distribution Lists:</strong>
    <input type="hidden" name="customerId" id="customerId" value="fe6fcdae-6159-44f8-8075-50a9fa272ece" />

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_12" name="All My Children">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">All My Children</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="12" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="All My Children" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_11" name="Winter is Coming">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Winter is Coming</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="11" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Winter is Coming" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_13" name="House Stark">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">House Stark</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="13" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="House Stark" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_7" name="Anderson and Axiom">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Anderson and Axiom</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="7" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Anderson and Axiom" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_10" name="Axiom without Luis">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Axiom without Luis</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="10" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Axiom without Luis" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_6" name="All except Bank">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">All except Bank</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="6" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="All except Bank" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_15" name="testing the list">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">testing the list</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="15" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="testing the list" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_9" name="Axiom">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Axiom</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="9" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Axiom" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_14" name="Axiom Emails">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Axiom Emails</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="14" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Axiom Emails" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to re-order this list when something new is added to it, thereby keeping the list in (case-insensitive) alpha order.

I've decided to allow plug-ins, as long as they are small. One I'm looking into is TinySort.

The ordering must be by the *name* property in the **row-fluid** divs.

The result would be:

```
<div class="span12" style="padding: 10px;" id="DLRemRows" name="DLRemRows">
    <strong>Member of Distribution Lists:</strong>
    <input type="hidden" name="customerId" id="customerId" value="fe6fcdae-6159-44f8-8075-50a9fa272ece" />        

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_6">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">All except Bank</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="6" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="All except Bank" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_12">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">All My Children</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="12" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="All My Children" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_7">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Anderson and Axiom</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="7" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Anderson and Axiom" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_9">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Axiom</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="9" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Axiom" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_14">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Axiom Emails</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="14" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Axiom Emails" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_10">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Axiom without Luis</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="10" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Axiom without Luis" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_13">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">House Stark</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="13" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="House Stark" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_15">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">testing the list</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="15" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="testing the list" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200);" id="row_11">
        <div class="span7" style="min-height: 25px;">Winter is Coming</div>
        <div class="span4" style="min-height: 25px; text-align: right;">                
            <input type="button" name="dlRemove" class="link btn-link dlRemove" value="Remove from List" />                
            <input type="hidden" name="distListId" id="distListId" class="distListId" value="11" />
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <input type="hidden" name="distListText" id="distListText" class="distListText" value="Winter is Coming" />
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

I already have the method that adds the rows of divs to the main parent div (*DLRemRows*), so I just need to come up with a function to do the sort of the rows after they're appended.

Comment: Please consider writing a library then when you say no custom code!! Any ways use `$('.row-fluid .span7').text()` to reorder the items

Comment: Here try this out `var arr = [];
$('.row-fluid .span7').each(function() {
 var obj = {
  $(this).text() + '' : $(this).parents('.row-fluid')
 }
 arr.push(obj);
 
 // This should produce array like
 // [{"All except Bank": HTMLOBJ}] HTMLOBJ => corresponds to your .row-fluid corresponding to the given text
 // Sort your array using name of the obj
});`

Comment: If you know an easy way to do this with TinySort, I'd be open to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It occured to be that I was being a tool by saying "No plugins", and I looked into a few. I wound up going with TinySort, which works admirably with a single line of code:

```
$('#DLRemRows > div.row-fluid').tsort({ attr: 'name' });
```

Comment: Great Job! Yo found the solution Yourself!

Comment: Yeah - There was a reason I wasn't going to "allow" plugins - I didn't want to inflate my codebase any more than it already was. But I realized that TinySort's minified js wouldn't really result in any bloat, and could do me some good. I must admit, I am a little confused as to why I got my question downvoted though.

Comment: not sure about the downvote. May be as it says no use of external library and no custom code either.